# Request for spring - controller works like synch or asynch mode?

Tags: java, spring

There is rest-controller on spring. I do post or get request using POSTMAN, is it synchronize or asych mode request ?

Comment: Every request is synchronous ,until you @Async in spring,Synchronous means further operation won't be executed until the current option is completed ,and asyncronous is when you are executing multiple operations at a time (achieved by multithreading )

Comment: @JaiDixit thanks, please craete answer and I will mark it as ok

Comment: Each request kicks off a new thread. So from a request standpoint, yes Spring executes asynchronously. That being said, if you make 4 concurrent request via postman or any client, each request will be served a response from a different thread. However, unless you use the `@Async` annotation on a given method call, all further method calls on that particular thread of execution will be synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every request is synchronous ,until you use @Async in spring,Synchronous means further operation won't be executed until the current operation is completed ,and asyncronous is when you are executing multiple operations at a time (achieved by multithreading ).Thanks